# Integrate annotation processor into the same project

Tags: java, spring, maven

Is it possible to use annotation processor in the same project where it is defined?

Example:

- src/

  - MyAnnotation.java
  - path_to_MyAnnotationProcessor.MyAnnotationProcessor.java
  - other classes
- resources

  - META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor
- pom

when I will run `mvn clean install`, I will expect that my processor will process classes annotated with MyAnnotation.

I don`t want to import already compiled processor from another lib, I just want to use it once I defined it in my src.

For now, I get error:
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-project: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Annotation processor 'path_to_MyAnnotationProcessor' not found`

part of pom.xml, where I ref. to my processors:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.plugin.compiler}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${version.java}</source>
                <target>${version.java}</target>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                       <proc>path_to_MyAnnotationProcessor.MyAnnotationProcessor</proc>
                    </annotationProcessors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Thanks to everybody, especially to @Stefan Ferstl and @yegodm. The solution came from yegodm is:
"One way is two have two modules in the same project. One module would define annotations and processor. Another would have it as a dependency to establish build order."

Comment: Have you tried it? :)

Comment: Have you tried it, replacing the metasyntactic  "path_to_MyAnnotationProcessor" with the actual  path to your annotation processor in your .pom?   (post your POM if so)

Comment: One way is two have two modules in the same project. One module would define annotations and processor. Another would have it as a dependency to establish build order.

Comment: if this is only solution, then I`ll do like this, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand.  Where is the FinalMethodsProcessor in your class tree?  You're not showing it in your layout.   Is it really in the default package?  Part of "other classes"?

Comment: Does the string "path_to_MyAnnotationProcessor" appear in your POM?  Or did you just add that manually to post to SO?

Comment: yegodm - Maven will know that compile phase dependencies get compiled first; there shouldn't be a need to make modules.

Comment: @BadZen Consider this is as a quick workaround. That's why I'm not making it an answer. For me it worked quite painlessly.

Comment: Ok, you've just updated the POM and changed it to literally include "path_to_MyAnnotationProcessor".   Sorry for the pedancy here, but you do understand that's got to be replaced with the package name where you annotation processor implementations live, yes?   Can you post your actual, complete POM?   This is rather like playing telephone... =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this problem is convert your project into a multi-module project where the annotation processor is in its own module. Having a different module for the annotation processor, you could use the quite new [`<annotationProcessorPaths>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#annotationProcessorPaths) option to define the annotation processor via `groupId`/`artifactId`.

The module using the annotation processor might need a dependency to the annotation processor module to get it built first.

**Note:** In a previous version of this answer I described an additional way to solve this problem, which apparently didn't work out of the box. That part has been deleted.

Comment: I tried this approach, but the same error - [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project my_project_name: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Annotation processor 'path_to_MyAnnotationProcessor.MyAnnotationProcessor' not found

Comment: BUT, the solution is to create multi module project and compile annotation processors module before module that uses it. And it works.

Comment: @IgorDumchykov Ok, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to force maven to publish the module with the annotation processor first? And also include it in the dependency chain resolution?

Comment: @PawelVeselov The only way I see (also described in the answer) is to add a dependency to the annotation processor module in the module where you need the processor. You could use the <provided> or <runtime> scopes for that.

Comment: "… compile annotation processors module before module that uses it …" This was selected as the accepted answer, but does it really work without manual fiddling? In a multimodule Maven project, can you simply run `mvn clean install` in the project root directory, and the annotation processor in `submodule-a` will be built and then used in `submodule-b`? If not, and if you have to completely build `submodule-a` manually first and then run some other command to build `submodule-b`, they might as well be in separate projects. Can someone clarify how this works?

Answer (score 2):

You could compile your processor earlier with a separate compiler execution.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-generator</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com/example/YourProcessor.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I've tested this, and it works - the processor does get invoked later during the actual compile phase.

If you precompile some other classes from the same project too, then you could directly reference and use them in the processor. That could be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it works but the class has to use the path separator char / instead of .